# Given optimality of L1 norm, prove that absolute value of sum of a vector with proper sign is less than 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, convex-optimization, vector-spaces, matrix-inverse

**Problem:**

Given a domain $\mathcal{D}\subset\mathbb{R}^{l}$, we can find $l$
points $\boldsymbol{v}_{i}\in\mathcal{D}$, $i=1,\cdots,l$. Each
point is a column vector with dimension $l\times1$. They form a matrix
$\mathbf{V}$, $
\mathbf{V}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\boldsymbol{v}_{1}, & \cdots & ,\boldsymbol{v}_{l}\end{array}\right]
$.
Denote the set of all such $\mathbf{V}$ that is invertible as $\mathcal{V}$.
That is,
$$
\mathcal{V}=\{\mathbf{V}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\boldsymbol{v}_{1}, & \cdots & ,\boldsymbol{v}_{l}\end{array}\right]:\boldsymbol{v}_{i}\in\mathcal{D},\mathbf{V}\text{ is invertible}\}.
$$

Consider a given vector $\boldsymbol{y}$. For a $\mathbf{V}\in\mathcal{V}$,
define
$$
\boldsymbol{x}=\mathbf{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{y}.
$$

Denote $\mathbf{V}^{*}$ as the invertible matrix that minimizes the
L1 norm of $\boldsymbol{x}$. That is
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{V}^{*} & =\arg\min_{\mathbf{V}\in\mathcal{V}}\left|\left|\boldsymbol{x}\right|\right|_{1}\\
 & =\arg\min_{\mathbf{V}\in\mathcal{V}}\left|\left|\mathbf{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{y}\right|\right|_{1}.
\end{align*}
Denote $\boldsymbol{x}^{*}=\mathbf{V}^{*-1}\boldsymbol{y}$.

For an arbitrary $\boldsymbol{u}\in\mathcal{D}$, denote $\boldsymbol{z}=\mathbf{V}^{*-1}\boldsymbol{u}$.
If for each component of $\boldsymbol{x}^{*}$, we have $\left|x_{i}^{*}\right|\neq0$,
$i=1,\cdots,l$, prove that

\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{i=1}^{l}z_{i}\frac{x_{i}^{*}}{\left|x_{i}^{*}\right|}\right| & \leq1.
\end{align*}

**Things I have tried:**

I have also post this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4680108/given-optimality-of-l1-norm-prove-that-absolute-value-of-sum-of-a-vector-with-p) to reach out to more audience.

The case when $l=1$ is easy to prove.
Denote the domain $\mathcal{D}$ as $[a,b]$. For a given $y$, denote
the optimal value of $v$ that minimize $\left|\frac{y}{v}\right|$
as $v^{*}$. One can easily get that $v^{*}$ is either $a$ or $b$.

The optimal condition means that , $\forall u\in[a,b]$, we have
\begin{align*}
\left|x^{*}\right| & =\left|\frac{y}{v^{*}}\right|\\
 & \leq\left|\frac{y}{u}\right|.
\end{align*}
So
$$
\left|\frac{1}{v^{*}}u\right|\leq1,
$$
which is exactly the inequality we want to prove.
I also try some special cases when $l=2$, and the conclusion holds. But I cannot find a general proof for $l\geq2$.

I also asked ChatGPT 4 for help, but found no valid proof from it.
However, it gave some inspiration. [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) might be useful when considering replacing the $i$ column of $\mathbf{V}^{*}$ with $\boldsymbol{u}$
($\boldsymbol{y}$) and multiplying the resulted matrix with $\boldsymbol{y}$
($\boldsymbol{u}$).
But I got no further progress.

**About the domain $\mathcal{D}$:**

In the problem $\mathcal{D}$ should be compact, i.e., closed and bounded.

But it seems that $\mathcal{D}$ is not necessarily convex.
Consider the following toy and random example when $l=2$ and $\mathcal{D}$ is non-convex.

The domain $\mathcal{D}$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{D}=\left\{ \left(v_{1},v_{2}\right)^{\top}:v_{1}\in\left[-6,6\right],\left|v_{1}\right|\leq v_{2}\leq\frac{1}{2}\left|v_{1}\right|+3\right\} .
$$
One can easily see that it is non-convex in [this plot of $\mathcal{D}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdbmL.png).

The vector $\boldsymbol{y}$ is given by $\boldsymbol{y}=\left(9,-2\right)^{\top}$.
After some efforts, one can get that
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{V}^{*} & =\left[\begin{array}{cc}
6 & -6\\
6 & 6
\end{array}\right],\\
\boldsymbol{x}^{*} & =\left(\frac{7}{12},-\frac{11}{12}\right)^{\top}.
\end{align*}

We then have
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{z} & =\mathbf{V}^{*-1}\left(v_{1},v_{2}\right)^{\top}\\
 & =\left(\frac{v_{1}}{12}+\frac{v_{2}}{12},\frac{v_{2}}{12}-\frac{v_{1}}{12}\right)^{\top}.
\end{align*}

It is then
$$
|z_{1}-z_{2}|=\left|\frac{v_{1}}{6}\right|\leq1.
$$

By the way, the vector $\boldsymbol{y}$ can not be $\boldsymbol{0}$, and I think we can assume that the first component of $\boldsymbol{y}$ is non-zero
and scale it to 1.

In this way, $\mathbf{V}^{*}$ remains the same, $\left|\left|\boldsymbol{x}^{*}\right|\right|_{1}$ changes up to
a constant, $\text{sgn}(\boldsymbol{x}^{*})$ either remains the same or
is reversed. The conclusion will still holds if it is correct.

But I do not know whether this assumption helps.

Comment: Is $\mathcal D$ assumed to be convex?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. After trying some special cases with non-convex domain, I found this conclusion still holds. So, I guess the domain $\mathcal{D}$ is not necessarily convex. But I forgot to mention that $\mathcal{D}$ should be compact, i.e., closed and bounded. Will edit the post to include the special cases for illustration.

Comment: I think that it may be useful to look at the Fenchel-Rockafellar dual. Substitute $U=V^{-1}$ and rewrite your minimization problem as $\min_U \|Uy\|_1 + I_U(U)$, where $I_U$ is the indicator function of the set where $U^{-1}\in\mathcal{V}$. This has the form $\min_x F(Ax) + G(x)$ with convex $F$ and $G$ and linear $A$. The dual problem is $\max_z -F^*(z) - G^*(-A^*z)$ with Fenchel-conjugates $F^*$ and $G^*$ and the adjoint map $A^*$. Maybe this is helpful…